# C# How can I assign one identifier to multiple substrings without using If statements?

Tags: c#

I created a program that removes homonyms from two strings. Then it compares the two strings to see if they are equal. It works well, but I am having a problem.

I have a huge array of Homonyms. This isn't the full list:

```
string[] Homonyms = new string[] {
        "to", "too", "two", "for", "four", "theyre", "there", "their", "see", "sea", "by", "buy", "bye", "past", "passed", 
        "witch", "which", "whose", "whos", "hole", "whole", "right", "write", "serial", "cereal", "principle", "principal",
```

These two strings need to be equal:

```
s1 = "There are three seas";
s2 = "Their are 3 sees";
```

These two strings should not be equal:

```
s1 = "The bee is by the sea";
s2 = "The sea is by the bee";
```

I could create hundreds of If statements like this:

```
if (word == "sea" || word == "see")
        word = "ID123"; // identify which homonym
```

Do you know how I can do this easily without hundreds of If statements?

Comment: where is `word` come from ?

Comment: Your homonym array isn't really useful for the purpose you're describing. You can't assume, just because two words are in that array, that they're homonyms of each other. They're not related to each other, or to a common ID like "ID123".

Comment: I agree with @StriplingWarrior. you need a mapping here to group the homonyms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments the fact that a word exists in the homonym array doesn't mean that two words are indeed homonyms of each other.

With that in mind what we have to do is to create a container that does groups the homonyms words.

I have created an exhaustive list of homonyms in a text file grab it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3v85a0wcwhdu8wq/TextFile1.txt?dl=0)

The text file can be added into your solution.

So the a huge array of Homonyms problem is solved.

As you can see each line in the file contains the homonyms that refer to each other ( they are separated by a '/' ) - now we can traverse the file and store them into an object:

```
    public class Mapping
    {
        public char Sort { get; set; }
        public List<string> Homonyms { get; set; }
    }
```

For example `there/they’re/their` will be stored in the same object.

The logic will be simple and it assumes that the two strings (s1 and s2) have the same numbers of words.

We analyse one word at the time from both strings(wordString1 and wordString2). If the word are the same is all good.

If the words are not the same - we search the list of mapping and see if it contains wordString1. If that is the case we check whether the same object contain wordString2.

If so wordString1 and wordString2 are homonyms and we continue the analysis. Otherwise we stop as it is obvious that the string s1 and s2 are not the same.

Here you can see both examples provided. Note that 3 and three are not considered homonyms in the English dictionary - therefor I have removed them. Feel free to add your numeric mapping if necessary.

[image]

[image]

Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public class Mapping
        {
            public char Sort { get; set; }
            public List<string> Homonyms { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            bool areTheSame = true;
            var string1 = "There are seas";
            var string2 = "Their are sees";
            //var string1 = "The bee is by the sea";
            //var string2 = "The sea is by the bee";

            var s1 = string1.Split(' ').Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToArray();
            var s2 = string2.Split(' ').Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToArray();

            List<string> homonyms = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Alex\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\TextFile1.txt").ToList();
            List<Mapping> mapping = new List<Mapping>();

            foreach (string item in homonyms)
            {
                var g = item.Split('/');
                Mapping element = new Mapping();
                element.Sort = g[0].ToUpper()[0];
                element.Homonyms = new List<string>();
                element.Homonyms.AddRange(g.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList());

                mapping.Add(element);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Analising...'{0}' and '{1}'", string1,string2);

            for (int i = 0; i < s1.Count(); i++)
            {
                string wordString1 = s1[i];
                string wordString2 = s2[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Word '{0}' and word '{1}'", wordString1, wordString2);

                if (wordString1 != wordString2)
                {
                    //check whether they are Homonyms
                    var sort = wordString1.ToUpper()[0];
                    var potentiallHomonym = mapping.Where(item => item.Sort == sort && item.Homonyms.Contains(wordString1)).ToList().FirstOrDefault();

                    if (potentiallHomonym != null)
                    {
                        if (potentiallHomonym.Homonyms.Contains(wordString2))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Those words are Homonyms, enter to continue analising.");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            areTheSame = false;
                            Console.WriteLine("Those words are not Homonyms.");
                            Console.ReadLine();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Those words are the same");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }

            if (areTheSame)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The strings are the same");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The strings are not the same");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```